# How to convert interactive Jupyter notebook with nbconvert to html

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, altair, nbconvert

I tried converting my notebook to nbinteract but the altair charts are not rendering. I also tried using nbconvert, the chars are working but the widgets are not.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --template nbconvert_template_altair.tpl --execute  Analysis.ipynb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an nbconvert template like the one shown here: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/329#issuecomment-473524751

Comment: Yeah, i actually saw that but the ipywidgets is not working. (Though the altair chart works perfectly fine)